# Usage of pushf in nasm

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I found that `pushf` is following the `aaa` instruction in my code.
What does this instruction actually do? After searching in Internet it says it pushes flags, but I doesn't understand which flag it will push on the stack and how can we access them.

Code snippet is given below:

```
mov al,[num1+esi]
mov bl,[num2+esi]
adc al,bl
aaa
pushf
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register

Comment: It pushes the flags effectively saving them on the stack. I suspect that after `pushf` there is some instruction like `or` (maybe even `or al, 0x30` to convert a digit to ASCII) that will clobber the flags and then a `popf` to restore them. This kind of code is often used to propagate a carry flag through to the next loop iteration if there are instructions that need to be done that may alter the carry flag. Any chance you are adding two ASCII strings containing numbers?

Comment: And if it was `pushf` `or al, 0x30` `popf` that this code was using then changing it to `lea eax, [eax+0x30]` may even work as it would have the same effect as converting a value in _AL_ to an ASCII character without actually modifying the flags (and thus not needing to save restore the flags)

Comment: If you don't need the value of `bl` for anything more than the `adc` you should be able to replace `mov bl,[num2+esi]` `adc al,bl` with `adc al,[num2+esi]`

Answer (score 3):

`pushf` pushes the content of the [flags register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register) on the stack.  This register contains all the flags you might care about.  For how to access it, well, after it has been pushed on the stack it's on the stack, so you can use anything you normally use to access things on the stack.

This answer might seem like it doesn't tell you much new, but that's really all there is to it.  There is no magic involved or anything weird.